# track marketo landing page views/hits in salesforce

Tags: landing-page, marketo

I can't seem to get a definitive answer on this. I've checked the docs which make no mention of it, but it seems like something that the Marketo integration should be able to do. Can someone please tell me if it is possible to track Marketo landing page hits/views from inside of Salesforce?